# get the values from 1 Matrix column into a dropdown select for another Matrix field column in another Channel

Tags: matrix, playa, drop-down

So I have 2 channels:

Channel NEIGHBORHOOD has a Matrix Field called "neighbors" and it gathers a list of people's names and info on them.

Channel EVENTS has a Matrix field called "guests" and I want to have a drop down that pulls all the neighbor names into a drop down.

I tried making the Matrix cell a Playa field but it pulls in only the neighborhood title.
I tried P&T Dropdown but it was manual entry of the drop down options.

Is there any way to get the values from 1 Matrix column into a dropdown select for another Matrix field column??

OR

Is this even possible w/out Matrix - I tried a new Playa/Relationship/Select field and none allowed me to do this at all... They all seem to only use the title.